# How to use Oracle function SYS_EXTRACT_UTC in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

We have index created in oracle using SYS_EXTRACT_UTC function as we are migrating to postgres so how to use the same in postgres index .

In oracle the index created is :-

```
create index TAB_XYZ_CREATED_DT_IX01 on TAB_XYZ (SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CREATED_DT));
```

When writing it in postgres

```
create index TAB_XYZ_CREATED_DT_IX01 on TAB_XYZ (CREATED_DT at time zone 'UTC');
```

but getting error while running above DDL

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "time"
> LINE 1: ...TAB_XYZ_CREATED_DT_IX01 on TAB_XYZ (CREATED_DT at time zone ...
>                                                              ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 64
> ```

Need to create same index in postgres

Comment: `created_at at time zone 'UTC'`?

Comment: its giving error ...  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "time"
LINE 1: ...TAB_XYZ_CREATED_DT_IX01 on TAB_XYZ (CREATED_DT at time zone ...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simply a missing pair of parentheses that is syntactically required to distinguish columns and expressions:

```
create index TAB_XYZ_CREATED_DT_IX01 on TAB_XYZ
   ((CREATED_DT at time zone 'UTC'));
```